Should low-scoring meta questions no longer be hidden on the Meta.SO home page, as was done on Meta.SE?
Yesterday, the Meta Stack Exchange home page was changed to no longer hide questions with below -8 score. Per the comments there, this was implemented only on the global meta and not per-site metas, with those having to manually request it.
Should this feature change be implemented here on Meta Stack Overflow as well?
The main case that was brought up there is that of unpopular staff questions being hidden despite their importance as announcements. I've seen that happen quite often here on Meta.SO in addition to the global meta. Another case I can think of is when someone makes a weak feature request then someone answers it with a stronger case to implement it but that case is never seen due to the question's low score - see also this prior feature request asking for heavily-downvoted answered questions to not be hidden on the home page.

It should be noted that just using the /questions path (all questions) always did that and still does it everywhere. And I think that was the norm once even for the main url of each exchange.

Yes, +1. If meta SO makes changes that are poorly recieved, our options are either "downvote into obscurity so nobody notices and objects" or "don't downvote, forfeit our best way of showing disagreement". Implementing this could help real action happen in response to bad decisions by SO.

@JoshBrunton In an ideal situation, there'd be two sets of votes on meta posts: one for the quality or usefulness of the post itself, like how voting is on main sites, and another for whether one agrees or disagrees with the post. That way, you could hide the truly un-useful posts while not hiding posts that are merely disagreed. On Meta.SE, where voting affects reputation, the latter type of vote would not affect one's rep in any way.

Yes, it should be implemented on Meta Stack Overflow also. The points you brought up are good examples to make a case for this.
Having that transparency will be positive, as users will be able to see what kinds of questions tend to get downvoted, and can use that information to improve their own contributions. If a heavily downvoted question is never seen, the same question is more likely to be asked again - and be poorly received again.
It may also shed light on any unusual downvoting patterns, such as from sock puppets, for example.
There really aren't many good reasons for hiding unpopular questions. But if it is to be done, the right way to do it would be by offering users the option to hide such questions via an opt-in setting.

If a heavily downvoted question is never seen, the same question is more likely to be asked again - and be poorly received again. This is also a great argument for disabling the Roomba criterion that deletes all unanswered questions with a score of -1 or lower on meta sites, especially if there's a valuable discussion in the comments. There is more hope in implementing the feature: the more likely such a question is to be seen, the higher chances someone will post an answer that'll prevent the question from being deleted.

Why would anyone go to the trouble of downvoting using a sock puppet on Meta?

I do agree with implementing it on Meta but "downvoted question is never seen" is kind of incorrect, they are only hidden on the homepage of Meta and can be still seen from the questions page, it's a known feature that the homepage tends to show a selective view of the questions list.

@RobertLongson If one wants to delete an unanswered question with a positive score, they can downvote it with sockpuppets to push it to Roomba.

@gparyani unless it's closed, it will not be deleted.

@Braiam I'm talking about RemoveDeadQuestions. That doesn't check closure status; it only checks if a question has no answers, isn't locked, and has a negative score.
